# C# - Binary Tree Issues

Tags: c#, binary-tree, ref

To the best of my knowledge my program  *should* work, however, I'm having difficulties with the *ref* keyword. We aren't expected to use an Insert() method, yet. However, I'm having a hard time trying to use the traverse methods as every time I get an error, it's regarding the ref either an argument is missing or something else. I know I've probably messed up my Main method, but that's due to experimenting and trying to get it to work. I do have a NodeClass with Get and Setter methods, however, the issue is essentially the ref keyword. What am I missing? I've added string I get an error, I've tried to use buffer I get an error.

BinaryTree Class-

```
 class BinTree<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        private Node<T> root;

        public BinTree()  //creates an empty tree
        {
            root = null;
        }
        public BinTree(Node<T> node)  //creates a tree with node as the root
        {
            root = node;
        }

        public void InOrder(ref string buffer)
        {
            inOrder(root, ref buffer);
        }

        private void inOrder(Node<T> tree, ref string buffer)
        {
            if (tree != null)
            {
                inOrder(tree.Left, ref buffer);
                buffer += tree.Data.ToString() + ",";
                inOrder(tree.Right, ref buffer);
            }

        }

        public void Preorder(ref string buffer)
        {
            PreOrder(root, ref buffer);
        }

        public void PreOrder(Node<T> tree, ref string buffer)
        {
            if (tree != null)
            {
                buffer += tree.Data.ToString() + ",";
                PreOrder(tree.Left, ref buffer);
                PreOrder(tree.Right, ref buffer);
            }
        }

        public void postOrder( ref string buffer)
        {
            PostOrder(root, ref buffer);
        }

        public void PostOrder(Node<T> tree, ref string buffer)
        {
            if (tree != null)
            {

                PostOrder(tree.Left, ref buffer);
                PostOrder(tree.Right, ref buffer);
                buffer += tree.Data.ToString() + ",";
            }
        }
    }
```

Program Class-

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BinTree<int> tree = new BinTree<int>();

        Node<int> root = new Node<int>(6);
        root.Left = new Node<int>(15);
        root.Left.Right = new Node<int>(654);

        tree.InOrder(ref , root.Data);




        System.Console.WriteLine(); 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Could someone possibly help me? Thank you.

Apologises in advance if it's something obvious.

Comment: Is the expected output `15,654,6,`?  As that is what I am getting after cleaning it up a little.

Comment: That is correct. I'm using Traverse methods; inOrder, PreOrder and PostOrder. :)

Comment: This what I am currently working with: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9glXXY

Comment: 1) you need to decalre a string (`string output;`), 2) pass the string by reference (`tree.InOrder(ref output);`).  I would note that you may be better off passing a `StringBuilder` instead of a string reference to reduce the number of memory allocations (plus you don't need `ref` in that case). Either that or _return_ a string, appending the current node to the passed in string.

Comment: @jrbeverly It's working mate. Want to post the answer, so I can accept it? :)

Comment: @DStanley I've been reaching the web and many people has recommended StringBuilder, however, we've been instructed to use it this way. But thank you. I know I messed up, I didn't declare a string. It makes sense now after seeing jrbeverly's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above common chain:

- You need to pass the `root` node into the `binTree` otherwise it will not be able to do anything in the `inOrder` methods. (`BinTree<int> tree = new BinTree<int>();`)
- You need a `string` to pass into the `inOrder` method call.  You can use [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to improve performance and remove reliance on `ref`

The [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9glXXY) contains a copy of the code with adjustments.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, breakdown and example. :)